# Stripe javascript submits form as HTML, when it should be JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I've created a form that has `remote: true` set on, and the create action responds to JS. Now when I added Stripe:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');
  $form.submit(function(event) {
    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

    // Request a token from Stripe:
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from being submitted:
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  // Grab the form:
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) { // Problem!

    // Show the errors on the form:
    $form.find('.card-payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

  } else { // Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
    var token = response.id;

    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));

    // Submit the form:
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
</script>
```

even though my form has been set as remote, it submits it as an HTML. So I get redirected and the controller returns `ActionController::UnknownFormat` because it doesn't know how to respond to HTML.

How can I make Stripe work the way it's supposed to, but have it not trigger the form as HTML. In console it also confirms: `Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML`

Answer (score 1):

In the `stripeResponseHandler` callback, you're submitting the form:

```
// Submit the form:
$form.get(0).submit();
```

This bypasses Rails' `remote: true` mechanism. Since you want to send the token in an AJAX request, you need to do this explicitly in the handler, by calling `$.ajax(...)` rather than `$form.get(0).submit`.

I found [this blog post](http://www.rubyeffect.com/blog/stripe-remote-form-submission/) that explains how to do exactly that!